# Decision boundary is not a property of training data in classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification

In ML videos of Andrew Ng on Coursera on Classification (in the third video), he said that the "decision boundary is not a property of the training set". What does this statement mean? And does it also imply that the straight line or any curves that we use in linear regression to fit data are not a property of the training set?  He claims that those curves (achieved through linear regression) aren't the properties of the corresponding training data. I am a bit confused about this. Kindly if my doubts could be removed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision boundary is a property of your classifier. Different classifiers lead to different decision boundaries.

Decision boundary has nothing to do with linear regression, as it only makes sense for classification problems. The decision boundary is the curve (or surface, in more than two dimensions) that splits the elements of the two different classes in your classification problem. In *logistic regression*, the decision boundary is a straight line, while in nonlinear classification methods, like neural networks, the decision boundary is a curve.

Comment: Thank you for your response. OK. But does it mean that e.g. a straight line that we use to fit data in linear regression, also is not a property of training data.

Comment: When you fit a linear regression to your data, you are using a linear regression model: then, the straight line is a property of the model. However, since it has been trained on your training data, it has both information from the model (the fact that is a straight line is because the model was linear regression) and the data (the fact that it fits your data is because of the data you have).

Comment: Did I answer your question? @swam

Comment: So would it be appropriate to say that for a given training data, and by using linear regression only one straight line would exist that will perfectly fit that data. But, when we use logistic regression in a classification problem on another data set a decision boundary is something which can not change when even when we use a different data set.